# Javascript breaking after an if statement

Tags: javascript, ajax

I can't figure out why everything inside the request.onreadystate function up to the comment works but the following alert()'s do not. The script seems to break after the if statement.

I'd really appreciate someone looking at my code for me. Thanks a lot.

```
    function positionHandler(position) {
        if (!document.getElementById("span")) document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));            
        document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = "("+position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude+")";
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.asycnc = false;
        request.open('GET','get.php?latitude='+position.coords.latitude+'&longitude='+position.coords.longitude);
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState != 4) return false;
            else if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                var results = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('note');
                for (var i in results) {
                    if (!document.getElementById(results[i].getAttribute('id'))) {
                        var note = document.createElement('div');
                        note.innerHTML = results[i].childNodes[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        note.id = results[i].getAttribute('id');
                        document.getElementById('main').appendChild(note);
                        //everything up until this point works
                    }
                }
                alert("this doesn't work 1");
            }
            alert("this doesn't work 2");
        }
        request.send(null);
        alert("this does work!");
    }

    var position = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(positionHandler);
```

Comment: Anything visible in error log?

Comment: Try to put other alerts, for example where you wrote the comment and immediately after the if statement. Moreover Firebug will help you (Console tab).

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors?

Comment: for (var i in results) is unsafe, you may iterate over inherited properties defined on the prototype chain, and your code inside the loop would probably break on such a property before you reach the end of the loop. And you would not see the error because a failure in an asynchronous answer is not reported. Try to add a try/catch, then either iterate with a counter or add a check that results.hasOwnProperty(i).

Comment: I'm testing code on iphone because the desktop browsers seem unreliable with geolocation, so I can't access the console. Thanks for the help, but Peters answer was perfect.

Comment: I was premature in marking this question answered and you are right Eric, I change my for loop to for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) and it seems to work now. I am just learning, so thanks for your help.

Comment: Eric should add his comment as an answer or you should answer yourself, else this question will remain open indefinitely? Glad you found the correct solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of your statements.

```
function positionHandler(position) {
    if (!document.getElementById("span")) document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));            
    document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = "("+position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude+")";
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.asycnc = false;
    // set the eventhandler logic
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState != 4) return false;
        else if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            var results = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('note');
            for (var i in results) {
                if (!document.getElementById(results[i].getAttribute('id'))) {
                    var note = document.createElement('div');
                    note.innerHTML = results[i].childNodes[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    note.id = results[i].getAttribute('id');
                    document.getElementById('main').appendChild(note);
                    //everything up until this point works
                }
            }
            alert("this doesn't work 1");
        }
        alert("this doesn't work 2");
    }
    // the event will be triggered here
    request.open('GET','get.php?latitude='+position.coords.latitude+'&longitude='+position.coords.longitude);
    request.send(null);
    alert("this does work!");
}

var position = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(positionHandler);
```

The reason is that you are setting the handler after it has already been called by the `request.open(...)` statement.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This line --> alert("this doesn't work 1"); won't work because probably the loop is infinite.
This line --> alert("this doesn't work 2"); will only work if this condition `else if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)` is false.

The third alert should work if you fix the first alert issue. Please check on your loop.

Best,

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the code. `for (var i in results)` will enumerate through a finite number of items. So the first alert *should* fire. The second alert is not governed by the `else if` statement, so *should* fire regardless.

Comment: I meant you can do like. results.each(function(i,v){});